# Smooth Scroll and Bootstrap Table Navs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and it works great; it smooth scrolls to the hash/id and subracts the height of the header.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
        $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var hash = this.hash;

            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery(hash).offset().top - 45
            }, 1500, function(){});
        });
    });
```

However I also have a bootstrap table on the same page with nav-links/tabs.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="all-units-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#all-units" role="tab" aria-controls="all-units" aria-selected="true">all-units</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="small-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#small" role="tab" aria-controls="small" aria-selected="false">Small</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="medium-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#medium" role="tab" aria-controls="medium" aria-selected="false">Medium</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="large-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#large" role="tab" aria-controls="large" aria-selected="false">Large</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="rv-vehicle-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#rv-vehicle" role="tab" aria-controls="rv-vehicle" aria-selected="false">Vehicle</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

My problem is this: When I click on one of the nav tabs, it is obviously an href tied to a hash/id, so when I click on it it jacks the scroll and keeps subtracting the height of the header (-45) as well as making a user unable to scroll if they click a tab link.

Is there a way I can still have the nav-tabs functional and the smooth scroll to id functional , without the smooth scroll occuring when a user clicks a nav tab?

Should I change the tabs to pills or buttons that filter the data like the tabs or will this cause the same issue?

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `.not` selector to filter out the `nav-link`s:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').not('.nav-link').bind('click.smoothscroll', function(e) {
```